# Question mark (?) symbol printed in java Stack Trace

Tags: java, soap, jbossfuse

I am running Fuse ESB SOAP service on a karaf docker container.

JAAS Basic authentication is implemented in this service. For wrong credentials, I am getting expected authentication error in the fuse logs but I am also getting  ? symbol in the java stack trace logs. Below is the snapshot of logs with ? symbol highlighted.

Also I am not getting any such ? symbol, when the same code is run in an older version of karaf. (pictures attached)

With ? symbol.
[4.2.6.fuse-750016-redhat-00001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL4H5.png)

Without ? symbol
[2.4.0.redhat-630262](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhU0f.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Fuse 7.5, then what's rendering the stack trace is `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ExtendedStackTraceElement` class used by pax-logging 1.11 and pax-logging-log4j2 used by Fuse 7.

Fuse 6.x on the other hand uses pax-logging 1.9.1 and pax-logging-service bundle, which is based on Log4j1 and the rendering of stack trace elements depend on ... Karaf's endorsed `$FUSE_HOME/lib/endorsed/org.apache.karaf.exception-2.4.0.redhat-630262.jar` library.

So simply - the stack traces are formatted using different mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes I am upgrading the services from Fuse 6.3.0 to Fuse 7.5.0. My concern is that is this ? symbol being used as a placeholder for some information which is failing to be printed ? If this is the case, then, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @AnkitGupta It looks like it's trying to print "*location: a classpath element or a jar*" and since Java classes are neither - they are part of the JDK - it displays `?` since it doesn't know where the class came from. If that's correct, their implementation could probably be improved

Comment: Can this issue be solved by making any configuration level changes via property files etc?

Comment: Nope. There's nothing to solve actually... Check http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout and description of `ex|exception|throwable` configuration property to configure how stack traces are formatted.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Thank you. I went through your provided links and it is helpful. Do you know where the default formatting for throwable is set in karaf ?

Comment: Without `throwable` option in the pattern, default `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableFormatOptions` are created, equal to `throwable{full}{separator(\n)}`